# Android linkify without first character

Tags: android, regex, textview, linkify

I'm using Linkify to detect tags(#) in a TextView.

```
Pattern userMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\B@[^:\\s]+");
String userViewURL = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/";
Linkify.addLinks(tvComment, userMatcher, userViewURL);
```

The url is supposed to end up with this text without '#' character.

I want to use it to search Instagram:

https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/mytag

but Linkify opens a url with '#' character:

https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/#mytag

How can I remove '#' character from the link created with Linkify.

Answer (score -1):

try this

`Linkify.TransformFilter transformFilter = new Linkify.TransformFilter() {
            //skip the first character to filter out '@'
            public String transformUrl(final Matcher match, String url) {
                return url.substring(1);
            }
        };`